# How to use QFileDialog::getsaveFileName to save a ui file with QFormBuilder?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

What I want:

When I call save(), I would like to use the QFileDialog to get the file, and save ui file with QFormBuilder(because it lets me save ui files recognizable by Qdesigner)

What I have:

I have a method called save()

```
void MainWindow::save()
{
    QString savef = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save"), "file", tr("UI files (*.ui)"));
    //here down I would like to use the savef to save ui file
    QFormbuilder builder;
    builder.save(savef, myui);

}
```

But savef is not QIODevice, and the Qt is complaining about it.

Any idea how I can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a QFile and pass that to save():

```
QFile out(savef);
if (!out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    const QString error = tr("Could not open %1 for writing: %2").arg(savef, out.errorString());
    //report the error in some way...
    return;
}

builder.save(&out, myui);

const bool flushed = out.flush();

if (!flushed || out.error() != QFile::NoError) { // QFormBuilder lacks proper error reporting...
    const QString error = tr("Could not write form to %1: %2").arg(savef, out.errorString());
    //report error 
}
```

When using Qt 5.1 or newer, I'd use [QSaveFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsavefile.html) instead:

```
QSaveFile out(savef);

  if (!out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    const QString error = tr("Could not open %1 for writing: %2").arg(savef, out.errorString());
    //report the error in some way...
    return;
}

builder.save(&out, myui);

if (!out.commit()) {
    //report error
}
```

Comment: That is nice answer. Nice to know about it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please also tell, why you would prefer QSaveFile? Any advantages?

Comment: Basically, more secure (no symlink attacks on Unix) and more robust: If you’re overwriting an existing file, the file won’t be corrupted if writing the new file couldn’t be completed for whatever reason (disk full, program error or crash…). The QSaveFile docs describes the behavior. So I always prefer QSaveFile for writing files to disk.

Comment: Thanks one more time.